# Prediction on multiple regression - Python

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, regression

I have 3 list of value and 1 ground truth data. They all belongs to the same  time series. My purpose is with 3 list try to forecast the ground truth data.

For example :

```
list1        = 15,224,32,14,55,67 
list2        = 21,331,42,41,31,43
list3        = 43,423,12,65,42,53
ground truth = 55,500,34,12,? ,?
```

I want to predict the ground truth new values depend on list1, list2, list3.

I looked this example but actually, I cannot understand how can i fit it for my problem.
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To moderators, I would recommend moving this to Stats stack exchange.

Comment: There is so much material available for Linear regressions Try the following.  http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html

Comment: I looked lots of staff like this but I cannot fit my problem. That is what i ask.

Comment: I hope the answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with something like this. I strongly recommend that you use pandas
 or something for data manipulation.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

def regressionSample():
    list1 = [15,224,32,14] 
    list2        = [21,331,42,41]
    list3        = [43,423,12,65]
    ground_truth = [55,500,34,12]
    listp1 =        [55,67] 
    listp2        = [31,43]
    listp3        = [42,53]    
    arr2 = np.transpose([list1,list2,list3])    
    tgt2 = np.transpose(ground_truth)
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(arr2, tgt2)
    print 'Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_ 

    # STart predicting and ploting
    predictArray = np.transpose([listp1,listp2,listp3])
    arrP = regr.predict(predictArray)
    pl.scatter(range(0,len(arrP)),arrP, color='blue',linewidth=3)        
    pl.show()
```

#Call demo method

```
   regressionSample()
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: I will give feedback as soon as possible,

Comment: I have modified the answer to score and predict "testing data"

Comment: I have a question on something. We know only 3 values for ground_truth list. Why we add 11 and 40 numbers to the ground_truth ?

Comment: those are just dummy values. This is data mining basics. You need training data and testing data. in this case arr2 is traing data and predictArray  will be your test data which you want to predict 

from your question you can pick values from list1,2,3 for which ground truth is available. This is just demo.

Comment: All you will need is to change the arrays

Comment: My latest edit would explain that